# Focus Issue when inserting a new input using ngFor

Tags: angular

I have a couple of requirements:

1. Load each item of a string array into inputs
2. Always have an empty input at the end of the list of inputs so that users can add to the array
3. Every time one of those inputs changes, post the change back to the server

I'm having a hard time doing this in Angular. The closest I've gotten is:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <div *ngFor="let title of titles; let i = index">
    <label>Box {{i}}</label>
    <input type="text" [id]="'box' + i"
    [ngModel]="titles[i]" 
    (keyup)="onKeyUp($event.target, i)"><br />
  </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  titles = ['1', '2', ''];

  onKeyUp(target, index){
    this.titles[index] = target.value;
    if(this.titles.length-1 === index){
      this.titles.push('');
      target.value = '';
    }
    document.getElementById('box' + index).focus();
  }
}
```

The only thing wrong here is that the focus needs to be on the input that the user is typing in and not moved to the input in the list when the user starts typing in the empty input. Any suggestion on how to solve this?

Plunk here: https://plnkr.co/edit/VuSR6C6g0vVOsRQEq5T2

**EDIT**

Thanks to Vega's answer below I came up with this solution that works perfectly:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <div *ngFor="let title of titles; let i = index; trackBy: trackByFn">
    <input type="text"
    [(ngModel)]="titles[i]" 
    (ngModelChange)="onChange($event, i)"><br />
  </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  titles = ['1', '2', ''];

  trackByFn(item, id){
    return item
  }

  onChange(target, index){
    if(this.titles.length-1 === index){
      this.titles.push('');
    }
    console.log(this.titles);
  }
}
```

It using the keyup event stopped firing properly when I change to a databound ngModel but after I switched to ngModelChange everything was great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add trackBy option on *ngFor  :

> Angular uses object identity to track insertions and deletions within
>   the iterator and reproduce those changes in the DOM.
>   ...
>   To customize the default tracking algorithm, NgForOf supports trackBy
>   option. trackBy takes a function which has two arguments: index and
>   item. If trackBy is given, Angular tracks changes by the return value
>   of the function.

```
<div *ngFor="let title of titles; let i = index; trackBy: trackByFn">
```

[demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/6QZquzR0vVI3D79QgaHt?p=preview)

[docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#syntax)

Comment: Thanks, the trackBy function was what I was missing. After I added it, switched to a databound ngModel, and changed to ngModelChange instead of keyup it works the way I need it to.